# Drupal add class to row specific to node type

Tags: css, drupal, view

In my Drupal template, I have a view loading multiple content types as fields. How can I apply css for certain types/add a class to the rows of a specific node type?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to override node--[contenttype].tpl.php and add the class after the    print $classes

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this would be to add a implementation of hook_preprocess_node(). As you have not stated the version of drupal you are using, I am going to presume you are using drupal 7.
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node().
 */
function hook_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $n = $variables['node'];
  if ($n->type != 'content_type_to_match') {
    return;
  }

  $variables['classes_array'][] = 'example-class';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    /**
     * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
     */
    function freeman_theme_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$variables) {
      foreach($variables['rows'] as $key => $row){
        if(is_object($row['content']['#node'])){
          $variables['rows'][$key]['attributes']->addClass('section-' .
          $variables["rows"][$key]["content"]["#row"]->_entity->bundle());
        }
      }
    }
```

Don't forget to replace views_view_unformatted with what you need